# Find Location where AD Group Resides

Tags: powershell

So we use a global group for our administrators separate of an admin group.

I would like to find where this group resides on our servers.

Using

```
Get-AdGroup "MyGroup" -server "myserver"
```

gives me the information of the group. but this group might reside like so.

```
3201CP10110-S\Administrators 
3201CP10111-S\Administrators 
3201CP10112-S\Administrators 
3201CP10114-S\Administrators 
3201CP10117-S\Administrators 
3201CP10118-S\Administrators 
3201CP10119-S\Administrators 
3201CP10119-S\BUILTIN\Administrators 
3201CP10119-S\BUILTIN\Remote Desktop Users 
3201CP1011A-S\Administrators 
3201CP1011B-S\Administrators 
3201CP1012-S\Administrators 
3201CP10120-S\Administrators
```

These are workstations and then the administrator group, and the global group resides in the administrators group.

Doing this manually for the 10,000+comptuers is going to be painstaking.

Can powershell  go through the server and extract anywhere that the group resides on?

So far all I can find is how to extract the members of the group that resides on the server... not helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: No, PowerShell does not have a native way to do that. You would need to scan every server/workstation you need to target and recursively scan each local group, per-box and probably store the results in a database to track it.

Comment: well, would there be a way to find which group the group belongs to? I can figure out the worstations based on that.

Comment: This might help: https://www.petri.com/get-local-active-directory-group-members-with-powershell